# Альтернатива кода JQuery на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Здравстуйте. Есть рабочий скрипт написанный на JQuery высветляющий значение "No Results" при введении в `input` несуществующего значения в таблице("Живой поиск"). Пробовал переписать самостоятельно, читать документацию, но безуспешно.
Работающий код в JQuery:

```
$(".search").keyup(function () {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $(".list").children().show();
    $('#noresults').remove();
    if (search) {
        $(".list").children().not(":containsNoCase(" + search + ")").hide();
        $(".list").each(function () {
            if ($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) 
              $(this).append('<tr class="noresults"><td style="text-align:center; font-size:17px; padding:25px 0 25px 0!important">No Results</td></tr>');
        });

    }
});

$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function (el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    return new RegExp(search, "i").test($(el).text());
};
```

Сам скрипт, собственно, взят [отсюда](http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/26/):

Неработающий код в чистом JS, переписанный мною:

```
document.getElementByClassName('search').onkeyup = function() {
      var search = this.value;
      document.getElementByClassName('list').children().show();
      document.getElementById('noresults').remove();
      if(search) {
        document.getElementByClassName('list').children().not(":containsNoCase(" + search + ")").hide();
        document.getElementByClassName('list').each = function () {
          if(this.children(':visible').length == 0)
            this.append('<tr class="noresults"><td style="text-align:center; font-size:17px; padding:25px 0 25px 0!important">No Results</td></tr>');      
        }
      }
    };

expr[":"].containsNoCase = function (el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    return new RegExp(search, "i").test($(el).text());
};
```

Особенно не могу найти альтернативу на JS для второй функции:

```
expr[":"].containsNoCase = function (el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
    return new RegExp(search, "i").test($(el).text());
};
```

Помогите переписать его на чистый JS. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте пример вашего кода, что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Пример работающего скрипта на JQuery:
[http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/26/)

Comment: Добавь пояснения какие именно элементы выбирает этот селектор: `containsNoCase`

Answer (score 1):

> Пример работающего скрипта на JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/26/

Построчный разбор...

```js
// $("#my-search-input").keyup(function () {
document.getElementById('my-search-input').onkeyup = function(e) {

  // var search = $(this).val();
  var search = e.target.value;

  // $(".my-list")
  document.querySelectorAll('.my-list').forEach(function(elem) {
    // .children()
    for (let child of elem.children) {
      // .show()
      child.style.display = '';
    }
  });

  // $('.noresults')
  document.querySelectorAll('.noresults').forEach(function(elem) {
    // .remove()
    elem.remove();
  });

  // if (search) {
  if (search) {
    // $(".my-list")
    document.querySelectorAll('.my-list').forEach(function(elem) {
      // .children()
      for (let child of elem.children) {
        // .not(":containsNoCase(" + search + ")")
        if (!containsNoCase(child, search)) {
          // .hide()
          child.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // $(".my-list").each(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.my-list').forEach(function(elem) {

    // if ($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) 
    if (!elem.offsetHeight) {
      // $(this).append('<tr class="noresults"><td colspan="3"><em>No Results</em></td></tr>');
      elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<tr class="noresults"><td colspan="3"><em>No Results</em></td></tr>');
    }
  });
}

// $.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
var containsNoCase = function(el, search) {
  // if (!search) return false;
  if (!search) return false;
  // return new RegExp(search, "i").test($(el).text());
  return new RegExp(search, 'i').test(el.textContent);
};
```

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  width: 300px;
}

table {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 24px 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input id="my-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search list" />
  <div class="something">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>2nd column</th>
          <th>3rd column</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="my-list">
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dolor sit</td>
          <td>100</td>
          <td>Wrong</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="something">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>2nd column</th>
          <th>3rd column</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="my-list">
        <tr>
          <td>Element</td>
          <td>321</td>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>More elements</td>
          <td>444</td>
          <td>Cowabunga</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>boom</td>
          <td>yo</td>
          <td>enough</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, покопавшись на разных форумах и посидев пару дней над документацией удалось переписать данный код. Кидаю рабочую версию на чистом JavaScript, может кому-то понадобится.

```
 document.getElementById("search-input").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
        let mylist = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
        for (let tbody of mylist) {
          let noresults = true;
          let noresultsrow = tbody.querySelectorAll(".noresults");
          if (noresultsrow.length > 0)
            for (let row of noresultsrow)
              row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
            for (let row of tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")) {
              let includes = row.textContent.toLowerCase().search(evt.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
              if (includes) noresults = false;
              row.style.display = includes ? "" : "none";
            }
            if (noresults) {
              tbody.innerHTML += "<tr class='noresults'><td style='text-align:center; font-size:17px; padding:25px 0 25px 0!important'>Brak wyników</td></tr>";
            }
        }
      });
```